# Azure Web App SQL Email Notifications

Tags: sql-server, email, azure, notifications

I'm just wondering what is the best (and most economical) way to do email notifications on an SQL database in Azure?

I've setup a web app and it uses an SQL database. In that database there are a couple of tables with Expiry Dates in. I want to send an email to the owner of that record (and possibly others) when the expiry date is approaching so for example 1 month before, 2 weeks before, 1 week before, 3, 2, 1 days before and on expiry. Then also on a weekly basis after expiry date keep notifying it is expired.

How would i do this?

Thanks

[UPDATE]
Just to clarify I've already setup an email client in my web app using SMTPClient. I'm looking how to setup the automated process to send such emails.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Email and Azure, the default choice is using SendGrid. And although SendGrid doesn't offer a Free pricing plan on their website anymore, you can choose the Free pricing tier when you create a SendGrid account through the Azure portal. It includes 25,000 emails/month.

Have a look at this article on how to: [How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email)

**After this addition:**

> how to setup the automated process of sending those kind of notification emails?

I would say: have a look at running a WebJob at a specified interval. WebJobs come for free with Web Apps, and can be seen as old-fashioned cron jobs. Getting stuff from a database and sending out mails based on the information sounds like an excellent task for a WebJob.

I would suggest you write a WebJob using the [WebJobs SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk), since this helps in getting stuff up & running pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks for your response Rick. Sorry its not what I meant. I've already setup emailing from my web app using SMTPClient. What I was looking for was how to setup the automated process of sending those kind of notification emails?

Comment: @SliderUK I've updated my answer. In short: WebJobs! They're awesome, come free with a Web App and are suited for the job.

Comment: Great I'll have a look at WebJob and see where I get to. Thanks

Comment: WebJob seems to have done the trick, thanks. This [link](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/creating-azure-webjobs.html) helped me quite a bit for those reading this thread.